# Mobile browser cannot play audio from local blob data

Tags: javascript, audio, blob

I want to play blob data (mp3).
I wrote code like this.
This code successfully doing in PC browser.
But Mobile browser cannot play.

```
//javascript source
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.src = url;
audio.load();
audio.play();

//html source    
<audio id="audio" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted codes. so I re-post.
startPlaying function will be called by button click action.

```
var blob;
// blob object has been created other logic.
function startPlaying(button) {
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  audio.src = url;
  audio.load();
  audio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome on Android, this does not seem to be possible - there is currently a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227476) for it.

(it was closed and marked as fixed, but as you can see from the comments, doesn't work for everyone - including myself).

Answer (score 0):

I needed only a localhost solution. My problem was solved when I enabled in chrome//flags the flag #enabled-unified-media-pipeline on Android.